# Selenium not working properly if tab not visible in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a browser scraping script which sends a message on WhatsApp web using selenium in python but yesterday noticed a that its sending half message or not sending messages. Debugged it and found that the browser window must be active to send messages my send message code as below.

```
def send_message(msg):
    whatsapp_msg = driver.find_element_by_class_name(send_messageClass)
    for part in msg.split('\n'):
        whatsapp_msg.send_keys(part)
        ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform()
    time.sleep(1)    
    ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_class_name` simply retrieves the element from the DOM. It does not ensure, if it is visible.

For this use [an explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in conjunction with visibility of the element as expected condition:

```
selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of(element)
```

This will wait for the element to be visible until the specified timeout is reached. Here is an example with timeout of 60 seconds:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EXP_CON

...

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
whatsapp_msg = driver.find_element_by_class_name(send_messageClass)
visible_whatsapp_msg = wait.until(EXP_CON.visibility_of(whatsapp_msg))
```

Comment: ActionChains not working, not writing a text when browser not visible

Comment: Exactly. `send_keys` does not operate on invisible elements. There is nothing you can do about it - except for ensuring that the element is visible before attempting to enter text.